# Why is $\tan(z)$ entire if $\tan(z)$ is not differentiable at $\cos(z)=0$

Tags: complex-analysis

The solution manual of my complex analysis textbook said that $\tan(z)$ is entire, why is that so, $\tan(z)$ is not differentiable when $\cos(z) = 0$

Comment: Not only is it not differentiable there, but it's not even continuous.

Comment: @BrunoJoyal:  Even more, not defined

Comment: What's the title of the book?

Comment: @Ross, that's arguable! They are not essential singularities, so it is meaningful to say that $f(z)=\infty$ when $\cos z=0$, or even to speak of the derivative $(Df)(z) : T_z \to T_\infty$, where $\infty \in \mathbf P^1$...

Comment: @BrunoJoyal:   I was claiming that a function cannot be continuous where it is not defined, based on the definition that $f(z)$ is continuous at $z$ iff $f(z)=\lim_{z\to z0}f(z)=f(z_0)$ which requires that $f(z_0)$ be defined.

Comment: @Ross I painted myself in the corner didn't I? :)

Comment: @BrunoJoyal: your first statement was correct. I was pointing out a generalization. I think OP was working in $\Bbb C$ so the second was not useful in this context, but may inspire future thoughts.

Comment: $\tan$ is a meromorphic function on the whole complex plane. Such a function is called an _entire meromorphic function_. When the context makes it clear (in the eyes of the author/speaker) that one deals with meromorphic functions, the adjective "meromorphic" is sometimes omitted. To judge whether it was a forgivable lapse to call $\tan$ entire, more context is needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your book is wrong. The function $\tan(z)$ is not entire, as you point out.